Как бот может получить ID сообщения на которое ответил пользователь (Телеграм aiogram)
Суть вопроса в том, что в группе с темами всегда сообщение отправляется как ответ на первое сообщение системы типа "Тема 22 создана". Я ботом хочу контролировать одну конкретную тему. Я так понимаю, мне нужно узнать ID этого первого сообщения при создании темы, чтоб понимать, что пользователь написал именно в эту тему.
Немного поправлю вопрос. Я то знаю ID темы, но не понимаю как бот может получить это ID чтоб дальше с ним работать?

telegram_id = message.chat.id этим кодом я получаю ID чата без учёта темы, результат типа -10023456789 а мне нжно чтоб бот видел в какой теме написал пользователь типа -10023456789_4

Для написания бота использую Python312 и библиотеку aiogram 3.14
Следующий код мне дает ID группы и имя пользователя который написал в группу любое сообщение
Как узнать, что он написал именно в нужную тему?
@dp.message()
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
          telegram_id = message.chat.id
          username = message.from_user.username
          await message.answer('Hello')


А в чём проблема то? Сохраняйте id сообщения в словарь, формата: {message_id: theme_id}, и проверяйте, если пользователь ответил на сообщение с id, которое есть в словаре, то мы извлекаем theme_id

Проблема в том, я начинаю изучать написание на Python. Вы говорите сохранять ID сообщения в словарь (в BD могу сохранить). Но я не понимаю как его (ID этго сообщения) узнать и как понять, что пользователь ответил именно на это сообщение.

Вроде нашёл как вычислить тему, в которую пишет пользователь:
@dp.message()
 async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    telegram_id = message.from_user.id # id пользователя
    ch_id = message.chat.id            # id группы
    username = message.from_user.username # имя пользователя
    n_thema = message.reply_to_message.message_id # id темы куда пришло сообщение
    await message.answer(f'Hello, {n_thema}') # визуальный тест переменной
    await add_to_database(telegram_id, username, ch_id) # занесение в базу данных нужные параметры

В итоге имеем и id группы, и id темы:
message_thread_id вместо message_id тоже даёт номер темы.
Разница в этом:

message_thread_id возвращает id темы в любом случае
message_id возвращает id темы, если обычная отправка сообщения, а если ответ на какое-то сообщение, то возвращает id того сообщения, на которое ответ.

